# Numpy zip array for LineCollection

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a simple way to zip numpy columns to be used as the input for a LineCollection?

#### Current Format

Note that the array has many more elements than what will be used.

```
arr=([(x1, y1, z1, a1, b1, c1), (x2, y2, z2, a2, b2, c2), (x3, y3, z3, a3, b3, c3)])
```

#### Desired Format

I would like to get lines in the following format so I might be able to use the LineCollection:

```
lines = [[(x1, x2), (y1, y2)], [(x2, x3), (y2, y3)] ...]
LineCollection(lines)
```

Comment: where does `[(2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]` come from?

Comment: apologies it was meant to be an example. Changed.

Comment: you do not need the `z1` , `z2` ?

Comment: I would just like the x and y. In reality the input array is much larger is size and I would only like select columns

Comment: If Kasra's answer doesn't solve your issue, can you give a bigger example ? What if there are `[(x1,y1,z1,a1,b1,c1),(x2,y2,z2,a2,b2,c2)]`

Comment: Larger example provided.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any direct numpy functions or such that would do the trick.

But if what you want is just the first two elements for each sublist , then you can try -

```
arr = [(1,2,3,),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6),(5,6,7),(6,7,8)]
lines = []
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    lines.append([(arr[i][0],arr[i+1][0]),(arr[i][1],arr[i+1][1])])

lines
>>> [[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(2, 3), (3, 4)], [(3, 4), (4, 5)], [(4, 5), (5, 6)], [(5, 6), (6, 7)]]
```

Comment: list comphrehensions makes it a little more compact, but a litte more obscure: `[[(arr2[i][0],arr2[i+1][0]),(arr2[i][1],arr2[i+1][1])] for i in range(len(arr2) - 1)]`

Comment: Yes , unless you have very very big lists (in arr2) , i would prefer the readable for loop over list comprehension . Only when the list is very very big would list comprehension give even a slight improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.T` method and `np.hstack` :

example :

```
>>> lines = [[(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]]
>>> np.hstack(numpy.array([np.array(i).T for i in lines]))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: this is not in the same form as the desired output?

Comment: @MattStokes Do you want the first 2 item in a list?

Comment: Larger example provided

Comment: I think you have this inversed